# If there is a question, with a number of answers, which doesn't really solves ones person problem, would asking the same question be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

The title basically says it all:

If there is a question, with a number of answers, and some of which are marked as `answered`, and where none of which doesn't really solves one persons problem - would asking the same question be a duplicate question?

Comment: Heh :) Irony :) It is not that of a duplicate - the answer there just says "it isn't a duplicate", but here some of the the answers clearly say how not to be considered as a duplicate, which is a better answer to my question.

Comment: Servy's answer says basically the same thing as deceze's answer: if the answers to that other question don't work for you, then it is by definition *not* a duplicate, because we define duplicate as "has the same answer". And both Servy and deceze recommend that you explain why your situation is different and why those other answers don't work for you.